# define $f(\mathbf{x})=f_1(x_1)+\cdots +f_n(x_n)$. Show that $f$ has a differential at each point of an n-dimensional interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Given $n$ real-valued functions $f_1, \dots, f_n$, defined and having finite derivatives in the interval $(a,b)$. For each $\mathbf{x}$ in the $n$-dimensional interval $$S=\{(x_1,\dots ,x_n)\mid a\lt x_k \lt b, k=1,2,\dots ,n\},$$

define $f(\mathbf{x})=f_1(x_1)+\cdots +f_n(x_n)$. Show that $f$ has a differential at each point of $S$.

From the book I got this problem, I need to show that there is a function $g$ such that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a neighborhood $N(x)$ such that $y\in N'(x)$ implies $$|f(y)-f(x)-g(x;y-x)|\lt \epsilon |y-x|.$$

Clearly the only candidate for such $g$ is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k '(x_k)t_k$. If I use this function then $$|f(y)-f(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k '(x_k)t_k|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n} (f_k '(c_k)-f_k '(x_k) (y_k-x_k)|\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f_k '(c_k)-f_k '(x_k)||y_k-x_k|$$. where c_k is some number between $y_k$ and $x_k$ obtained from Mean Value Theorem. However, I cannot progress further from here, unless I assume the continuity of the derivatives of each $f_k$'s, which is not given in the problem. How can I prove this problem?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to resort to the Mean Value Theorem here. Just use the fact that each $f_k$ is continuous, since it is differentiable. Then you can make $|f(y)-f(x)|$ arbitrarily small, and since each $f'_k(x_k)$ is finite, we can find a bound $M$ for all such derivatives, and we can find a neighborhood of $x$ that would make the sum of all $|y_k-x_k|$ sufficiently small.